# How do I apply method of the class to the property of the class?

Tags: vba

I have a class `ClsAnimal` containing the string property `species`, and also method `plural` which just returns a string with added "s" at the end of a string. I wonder if it's possible to apply `.Plural` to `Animal.Species` directly, as shown in the example below:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Animal As New ClsAnimal

    Animal.Species = "cat"

    debug.print Animal.Species
    'expected result "cat"

    debug.print Animal.Species.Plural
    'expected result "cats"

End Sub
```

`ClsAnimal` Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private PSpecies As String

Property Let Species(val As String)
    PSpecies = val
End Property

Property Get Species() As String
    Species = PSpecies
End Property


'returns the name of an animal + "s"
Private Function Plural(val) As String
    Plural = val & "s"
End Function
```

Comment: You can't do that because the return type of Species is String, and a string has no methods you can call on it.  Best you can do is `Animal.Plural(Animal.Species)`  Or if the only purpose of Plural is to pluralize Species then just have it get its `val` input from `PSpecies`

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of hack your way to the behavior you are describing. They way I could implement this is to create a new class that "extends" strings. I've called mine StringExt and it looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private pValue As String

'@DefaultMember
Public Property Get Value() As String
    Value = pValue
End Property

Public Property Let Value(val As String)
    pValue = val
End Property

Public Function Pluralize() As String
    Dim suffix As String

    'Examine last letter of the string value...
    Select Case LCase(Right(pValue, 1))
    Case "" 'empty string
        suffix = ""
    Case "s" 'words that end in s are pluralized by "es"
        suffix = "es"

    'Test for any other special cases you want...

    Case Else ' default case
        suffix = "s"
    End Select

    Pluralize = pValue & suffix
End Function
```

This is a wrapper class that wraps around an inner string value. It has a single method which will try to return the plural of the inner string value. One thing to note here is the use of a `DefaultMember`. I used a really handy vba editor COM addin called [RubberDuck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba) to do all the behind-the-scenes work for me with the Default Member. You can do it manually though. You would need to export the class module and modify it in a text editor, adding the `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0` tag inside the property getter:

```
...
Public Property Get Value() As String
Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Value = pValue
End Property

Public Property Let Value(val As String)
    pValue = val
End Property
...
```

Then, import the module back into your vba project. This attribute is not visible in the vba editor. More on default members [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx) but it basically means this property will be returned if no property is specified.

Next, we change up your animal class a bit, using our new StringExt type for the Species property:

```
Option Explicit

Private pSpecies As StringExt

Public Property Set Species(val As StringExt)
    pSpecies = val
End Property

Public Property Get Species() As StringExt
    Set Species = pSpecies
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pSpecies = New StringExt
End Sub
```

Note here that you'll now need to make sure the `pSpecies` field gets instantiated  since it is an object type now. I do this in the class Initializer to enure it always happens.

Now, your client code should work as expected.

```
Sub ClientCode()
    Dim myAnimal As Animal

    Set myAnimal = New Animal
    myAnimal.Species = ""

    Debug.Print myAnimal.Species.Pluralize
End Sub
```

**Disclamer:**

Substituting a basic string type for an object type might cause unexpected behavior in certain fringe situations. You are probably better off just using some global string helper method that takes a string parameter and returns the plural version. But, my implementation will get the behavior you asked for in this question. :-)